# Java : Can't capture console output of a console program (Blockland.exe)

Tags: java, stream, console

I'm trying to capture the output of a console program and write overwriting lines of the output to a file which another program will read, line by line I write into this file (the file should only contain one line at a time) but when I made this code and tried running it, it didn't work. The process started perfectly, but the file is not being created, written to, and I am not getting any System.out.println's of "Streaming : blah blah blah"

You can read the code below or use this pastebin : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Yahsqxma

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;



    public class OpenRC {
static BufferedReader consoleInput = null;
static String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
static Process server;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // OpenRC by Pacnet2013
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    if(os.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
        os = "Windows";
    }
    else if(os.indexOf("mac") >= 0) {
        os = "Mac";
    }
    else if(os.indexOf("nux") >= 0) {
        os = "Linux";
    }
    switch(os){
        case "Linux" : //cause I need WINE      
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/OpenRC.txt");

            try {

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
                    String path = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Got BlocklandEXE - " + path);
                    String port = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Got port - " + port);
                scanner.close();
                server = new ProcessBuilder("wine", path + "Blockland.exe", "ptlaaxobimwroe", "-dedicated", "-port" + port).start();        
                if(consoleInput != null)
                    consoleInput.close();
                consoleInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
                streamLoop();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("You don't have an OpenRC Config file OpenRC.txt in the directory of this program");
            }

    }
}
public static void streamConsole() 
{
    String line = "";
    int numLines = 0;
    try
    {
        if (consoleInput != null)
        {
            while((line = consoleInput.readLine()) != null && consoleInput.ready())
            {
                numLines++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("There may be a problem - An IOException (java.io.IOException) was caught so some lines may not display / display correctly");
    }
    if(!line.equals("") && !(line == null))
    {
        System.out.println("Streaming" + numLines + line);
        writeToFile(System.getProperty("user.dir"), line);
    }
}
public static void streamLoop()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("A slight problem may have happened while trying to read a command");
    }
    streamConsole();
    streamLoop(); //it'll go on until you close this program
}
public static void writeToFile(String filePath, String content)
{
    try {

        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("Creating new stream text file");
        }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Wrote stream text file");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running a DOS console application, which does not necessarily write to stdout or stderr, but it writes to the "console". It's nearly impossible to capture the "console" output reliably. The only tool that I have ever seen that is able to capture console output is `expect` by Don Libes, and that does all sorts of hacks.